# Find first n sums of a column, grouped by two other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have a table in SQL like this. Now I want to find sum of score grouped by column ID & Name, and show just two highest sums for each ID as below, so how can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group) Just change `1` to `2` in those answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like this:

```
Select ID, Name, Score From (
Select ID, Name, SUM(Score) score, row_number() over (partition by ID,Name order by SUM(Score) desc) rn 
from Table
group by ID,Name) allScores
where rn > 2
```

Comment: Almost solved the problem! I tried getting rid of 1 column in partition by clause, keep column ID only (=> partition by ID) and the column rn then returned the right values (at first it just returns 1 for all rows), so that ended up with the correct result. Thanks again, Ruben.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try This:

select top(2) Id , name , sum(Score) as sumScore
from table
group by id , name
order by sum(Score) desc